# php Programming Fatal Error Class 'input' not found in /home/adminl0gin/public_html/login.php on line 21

Tags: filepath, autoloader

I've been having this issue for a few days now and though I have made some progress I still have not gotten anywhere. The main issue is finding the classes and autoloading them dynamically as needed. The end result is the outputted error you see in the title of this post. 
File structure is as follows

- input.php
- core/

  - classes/
  - init.php
  - loader.php

Below is the corresponding code:

**login.php (Line 21)**

```
if (input::exists()) {
```

**init.php**

```
if (!defined('BASE_PATH')) {
define('BASE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__) . 'classes/');
require 'loader.php';
Loader::Register();
}
```

**loader.php**

```
class Loader {
public static function Register() {
    return spl_autoload_register(array('Loader', 'Load'));
}

public static function Load($strObjectName) {

    $strObjectFilePath = BASE_PATH . $strObjectName . '.php';

    if ((file_exists($strObjectFilePath) === false) || (is_readable($strObjectFilePath) === false)) {
        echo "there is a problem!";return false;
    } 
    else {
        require ($strObjectFilePath);
    }


   }
}
```

**error**
Fatal Error Class 'input' not found in /home/adminl0gin/public_html/login.php on line 21

Current php version is 5.4.24 on a live hosted server GoDaddy

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Please past code from login.php on line 21.

Comment: login.php (Line 21)

if (input::exists()) { <<---this is line 21 It calls the input class correctly. The only reason why I put focus on that singular line is because I know that's not where the problem is, in terms of how I called the class or anything else within that particular file. My focus is on discovering why it will not find a file that clearly exists within the dir. and fixing it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you added init.php in your login.php file?

Comment: I do apologize, but the problem was solved quite a while ago.